# How to Lock the Android Device Screen on Android 4.4 and 5.0+

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to lock the device screen. I was find the solution on the Internet and I use this tutorial http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html .Unfortunately, after tested then It not work for android 4.4 and 5.0+. It works well on Android 2.2+. So How to Lock the device screen for android 4.4 and 5.0+, not reduce brightness.

Comment: You have to install your app as the device administrator in order to perform this operation.

Here's the official documentation link to do that.
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: lock a transparent Activity to the screen bro